# How to place row values into new columns for readability?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table where separate rows exist for the same time period, one row per location:

```
+---------------------+----------+-------+-------------+
| time                | location | state | probability |
+---------------------+----------+-------+-------------+
| 2019-08-08 22:04:11 |        A |     0 |        0    |
| 2019-08-08 22:04:11 |        B |     0 |        0.2  |
| 2019-08-08 22:04:11 |        C |     1 |        0.48 |
| 2019-08-08 22:04:21 |        A |     0 |        0.18 |
| 2019-08-08 22:04:21 |        B |     0 |        0.22 |
| 2019-08-08 22:04:21 |        C |     1 |        0.92 |
```

It'd be so much easier to read if the columns looked more like:

```
| time                | A_st | A_pb | B_st | B_pb | C_st | C_pb | 
| 2019-08-08 22:04:11 | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0.2  | 1    | 0.48 |
| 2019-08-08 22:04:21 | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 1    | 0.92 |
```

Where multiple rows with the same time turn into a single row and their values slotted into the appropriate columns for that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select time,
       max(case when location = 'A' then state end) as state_a,
       max(case when location = 'A' then probability end) as prob_a,
       max(case when location = 'B' then state end) as state_b,
       max(case when location = 'B' then probability end) as prob_b,
       max(case when location = 'C' then state end) as state_c,
       max(case when location = 'C' then probability end) as prob_c
from t
group by time;
```